Common zeros of holomorphic one forms on Riemann surfaces
If $M$ is a genus 2 Riemann surface and $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are non-zero holomorphic one forms with simple zeros, then I think the two can't have a common zero unless they have exactly the same zeros.  Indeed, they both have two zeros and if there was one point of overlap, $\omega_1/\omega_2$ would be a degree one map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ contradicting $M$ having positive genus.
It seems this argument generalizes to genus $g>2$, i.e., if $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ have $2g-2$ simple zeros and share $2g-3$ of them, then they share all $2g-2$ zeros.
I'm curious if this is the best you can do?  If I understood the answer of Georges Elencwajg correctly, then it seems like the degree of $\omega_1/\omega_2$ should be $2g-2$ which suggests that there can't be any common zeros as in the genus two case.  However, this seems quite strong to me so I think I may be misunderstanding or overlooking something.
Edit:
Thinking about it some more I definitely misunderstood something.  In genus three suppose there were $\omega_1, \omega_2$ and $\omega_3$ holomorphic all with distinct simple zeros.  This would give linearly independent meromorphic functions $f_{21}=\omega_2/\omega_1$ and $f_{31}=\omega_3/\omega_1$.   However, for any given zero $p$ of $\omega_1$ one can look at the poles of $f_{21}$ and $f_{3,1}$ at $p$ and see there is a constant $\alpha$ so $h=f_{21}+\alpha f_{31}$ does not have a pole at $p$, but must still have at least two poles (as the functions are linearly independent and there can't be a meromorphic function with one pole for topological reasons).  It seems possible $h$ has to have exactly two poles but I have to think about it more.

Sketch of an idea: each of the two 1-forms is a section of the cabonical bundle, se their zero sets are (equiv. to) the canonical divisor. The degree of the canonical divisor is 2g-2, so if the zeroes are all distinct and 2g-1 of them coincide, I think it follows from the equiv. of the divisors that the last one should also coincide. I might type this into an answer later if you find it useful, let me know

Sure if you could give some other perspectives it would help me, though I think I have a grasp of the 2g-3 overlap case.  P.S. There was a typo in the question .
